How to filter two Excel columns to return rows with negative values in either column?
Given two (or more) columns of data as depicted in this
Image of Source Data

I would like to design a filter that returns only rows that contain a negative number in either column, as shown in these
Desired Result

I'm willing to filter using the Excel Filter UI on the ribbon, or with VBA, but can't seem to find the magic combination to return "all rows with a negative value in EITHER column."
I've tried Advanced Filtering (like that shown in the first image link above), but it seems to "AND" the filtering in the two columns, when I think what I am looking for would be an "OR" operation.  Perhaps if there were a way to specify the filter conditions for each column as "<0 or <blank>" then Advanced Filtering might work!
I've also tried variations of the following VBA code with no success (the following only returns the row with a negative number in BOTH columns - similar to results using advanced filtering)
'Filter "Column1"
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TRANSACTION_LOG_TABLE).ListColumns("Column1")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=.Index, Criteria1:="<0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=""
End With
'Filter "Column2"
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TRANSACTION_LOG_TABLE).ListColumns("Column2")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=.Index, Criteria1:="<0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=""
End With

I suppose I could perform intermediary steps to get the results of filtering each column independently and then merge them keeping only unique rows, but I'm hoping that there is a solution that doesn't require this type of intermediate processing.

I found my own answer after posting the question.   This Microsoft article on Advanced Filtering showed me how!  For brevity, this was the solution:
